# What does "CUSTOM BINARY DOWNLOAD" mean exactly?

Tags: recovery-mode, stock-android

When I boot an Android device into download/ODIN mode, on the top-left it says "CUSTOM BINARY DOWNLOAD (`n` counts)" where `n` may possible mean the amount of times the device has been flashed. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you guessed it right. It increases everytime you flash a ROM / kernel. It's also called [binary counter](http://www.droidviews.com/restore-galaxy-s3-to-stock-firmware/). It's one way of checking if your device has stock ROM or not

> The binary counter in a Samsung built device is a flip counter which turns up or increments a number after a non-official ROM is Installed.